# Create Java statements at run-time

Tags: java

Is it possible to create and execute java statements at runtime.

Statement like this:

```
Query q = new Query("type").setFilter(filter1).setFilter(filter2).setFilter(filter3).setFilter(filterN);
```

The problem I want to solve is the fact that the Query object here is immutable and I want to build it based on given set of parameters or arguments at runtime.

Enclosing it in a method like:

```
Query query = buildQueryFromArgs(type, filterList);
```

`buildQueryFromArgs` method essentially would create the java statement at the top.

**Cannot do this:**

```
for(Filter filter : filters){
 query = query.setFilter(filter); 
}
```

because what will happen here is that last filter will be the only one that is applied. Unless we do `query.setFilter(f1).setFilter(f2).setFilter(andSoOn);`

Comment: Looks like you can call `setFilter` on it as many times as you want; what prevents you from iterating over filters and doing that?

Comment: Look into the Builder pattern

Comment: Could you please explain in more details. Looks like you can just have a for-loop calling setFilter at each iteration, but you want something else, isn't it?

Comment: As in, your java code creates more java code and executes that code also ?

Comment: Looks like this is the answer to my question: http://bytebuddy.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you asking about something like

```
public static Query buildQueryFromArgs(String type, List<Filter> filterList){
    Query resultQuery = new Query(type);
    for (Filter f : filterList){
        resultQuery = resultQuery.setFilter(f);
    }
    return resultQuery;
}
```

Comment: The OP said that Query is immutable, so I'm assuming it doesn't really have a setFilter() method.

Comment: @Eran Being immutable doesn't mean that it can't create new Query with changed state. Same idea is shown in `String` where despite being immutable we have `replace` method. But you may be right since this matter is not explained clearly in question.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks for the code, I have updated my question for the case

Comment: @xybrek You claim that "*Cannot do this: for `for(Filter filter : filters){ query = query.setFilter(filter); }` because what will happen here is that last filter will be the only one that is applied.*" But then you say "*Unless we do `query.setFilter(f1).setFilter(f2).setFilter(andSoOn);`*" which kind of negates what you said before. I am assuming that you meant `query = query.setFilter(f1).setFilter(fN)`. In that case why do you think that this code is different that `query = query.setFilter(f1); query = query.setFilter(fN)`?

Comment: Since you claim that your Query is immutable then I assume that `query.setFilter(fX)` returns new `Query` object with filters which ware available for `query` plus `fX` filter. Is this assumption wrong? If so then I don't get how `query.setFilter(f1).setFilter(f2).setFilter(andSoOn);` can create query with set of filters `f1` `f2` `andSoOn` as you claim to happen in your question. So can you explain it more?

Comment: Maybe instead of passing filters multiple times you can pass one filter which will represents more filters like http://pastebin.com/uYzgu7RB

Comment: @Pshemo Here's a sample code I made to explain what I mean: http://pastekit.com/j2ZGy

Answer (score 1):

Why Not use a Builder ?

Something like this:

```
QueryBuidler qb = new QueryBuilder(type);
for (Filter f : filterList)
    qb = qb.setFilter(f);
Query query = qb.build();
```

Of course, the build() method would probably just call a constructor of Query that accepts a type and a list (or array) of Filters, so perhaps you can simply call that contructor in the first place and skip the QueryBuilder class.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**Solution #1**
Create a method like you said. This would be considered a *static factory method*. Although similar to a constructor, it allows you to specify an identifier (name). Although, if the name isn't a problem, static factory methods may overcomplex things; you could just pass the list and type into the constructor. Below is an example of a static factory method; using the constructor would require the constructor to be non-private:

```
class Query {
    private List<Filter> filters;
    private String type;

    private Query(String type, List<Filter> filters) {

    }

    public static Query buildWithFilters(String type, List<Filter> filters) {
        return new Query(type, filters);
    }
}
```

You would then call it like:

```
List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
//add filters

Query query = Query.buildWithFilters("type", filters);
```

**Solution #2**
The [Builder pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) allows you to set optional and mandatory the state of an object before building it. After building, the object can remain immutable.

```
class Query {
    private final String type;
    private final List<Filter> filters;

    private Query(Builder b) {
        type = b.type;
        type = b.filters;
    }

    private static final class Builder {
        private String type;
        private List<Filter> filters;

        public Builder(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public Builder addFilter(Filter filter) {
            if(filters == null)
                filters = new ArrayList<>();

            filters.add(filter);
        }

        public Query build() {
            return new Query(this);
         }
     }
 }
```

You can then construct your object like this:

```
Query query = new Query.Builder("type").addFilter(filter1).build();
```

The trick here is storing the state in a `Builder` instance before passing it to the instance you are trying to create. This allows you to first specify properties before creating the object, then construct the object with those properties through the builder'a `build()` method.

---

If you can't modify the `Query` class, your next option would be creating an immutable wrapper:

```
final class QueryWrapper {
    private final Query query;
    private final List<Filter> filters;

    private QueryWrapper(Builder b) {
        query = b.query;
        filters = b.filters;
    }

    public static final class Builder {
        private Query query;
        private List<Filter> filters;

        public Builder(Query query) {
            this.query = query;
        }

        public Builder addFilter(Filter filter) {
            if(filters == null)
                filters = new ArrayList<>();

            filters.add(filter);
        }

        public QueryWrapper build() {
            new QueryWrapper(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The wrapper allows you to encapsulate the `Query` instance. Clients then communicate with the `Query` through the wrapper; the wrapper controls the mutability.

The builder allows you to optionally add filters if you wanted. The wrapper is immutable, so we'd wanna specify optional filters before constructing the wrapper. The builder's constructor forces the client to pass in a `Query` instance (every wrapper must have a `Query`).

Comment: Can't modify the Query object because its library from GAE (Google)

Comment: @xybrek You could create a wrapper which encapsulates the `Query`. Updating answer now, will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take an example from SQL and use a PreparedQuery.

With PreparedStatements it prevents sql injection and it makes the query faster.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PreparedQuery